# BigQuery concatenate string and integer/timestamp?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery and am trying to create a String out of a timestamp int and a plain string. I've tried casting it to a string using `STRING()` but it does not seem to be working.

What can I do to convert everything within the `STRING()` function to a string?

```
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN STRING('intraday_' + FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY))) AND 'intraday_' + FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try below

```
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN CONCAT('intraday_', FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY))) 
              AND CONCAT('intraday_', FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: Was missing a `)` but seems to do the job, thank you!

Comment: Will do when available!